# Pre-encoding a json array

Tags: php, json, laravel

I'm making a request to my api to get some JSON data from a server but it seems the UTF-8 characters aren't correctly decoded. There is no problem with blade views but I dont want to use blade.My headers are :

```
Cache-Control:no-cache
Charset:UTF-8
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Type:application/json
Date:Mon, 31 Mar 2014 19:02:41 GMT
Server:nginx/1.4.7
Set-Cookie:laravel_session=eyJpdiI6IkFFWExRQjJjc1wvYngwbm5jUnV2R2tiQ1l4eE5ObmpIMVwvYVFHbEsxSXByTT0iLCJ2YWx1ZSI6InY2emRrMWZ4WkxIRGplZ1ZqOWIyaWp1VHFpU2ZpYlwvTmh4aURUd20yTzgwdjZwUXBOVWZkZmoydDB0KzJFOXhoUHR6dkoyaUptYVZnd0duNGNCQjhVQT09IiwibWFjIjoiMDZhMmMyOTk4NjEzMTk5ZjIwYjE0Yjc4MTdiOGZlYjUyYmQ5OGQ2ZDM2M2NiNzdkZTVkZWIxNGUxY2Q4ZTQxNCJ9; expires=Mon, 31-Mar-2014 21:02:41 GMT; Max-Age=7200; path=/; httponly
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
X-Frame-Options:SAMEORIGIN
X-Powered-By:PHP/5.5.10
```

My controller is :

```
public function getIndex(){
    $posts = Post::with('author','thumbnail')->where('id','<','150')->orderBy('created_at','DESC')->take(5)->get(); 

    $response = Response::json($posts);
    $response->header('Content-Type', 'application/json',''); 
    $response->header('Charset','UTF-8');


    return $response ;
}
```

here is a sample of what I am trying to clear:

```
comments = [{
    "id":149,
    "user_id":0,
    "title": "özlem güzelharcan"
  },{
    "id":239,
    "user_id":1,
    "title": "&Ouml;zlem G&uuml;zelharcan",
  }];
```

How can I pre-encode my json array to get Turkish escaped characters correctly ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

By reading Laravel code this seems to be the `json function`:

```
// vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/ Support/Facades/Response.php

public static function json($data = array(), $status = 200, array $headers = array(), $options = 0)
{
    if ($data instanceof ArrayableInterface)
    {
        $data = $data->toArray();
    }

    return new JsonResponse($data, $status, $headers, $options);
}
```

so I think you're able to pass your headers as array as the 3rd param but I suppose it carries the right Content-Type and the Charset.

Yes, here's the merged pull request:

> https://github.com/laravel/laravel/commit/d3ed53d48fb3429dfc2ce5e83d2022fc32acd4cd

---- EDIT ----

to clean your json:

```
$j = '[{
    "id":"149",
    "user_id":"0",
    "title":"özlem güzelharcan"
},{
    "id":"149",  
    "user_id":"0",
    "title":"&Ouml;zlem G&uuml;zelharcan"
}]';
```

you must decode those html entities:

```
$j = json_decode(html_entity_decode($j, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));

var_dump($j);
```

Comment: how does laravel escape those characters? Do you know where in source?

Comment: No, I'm editing the post in case you need to encode those html entities.

Comment: No but Laravel uses Symfony Response Component so I think somewhere in that component there will be a `json_encode($theData)`, I'm editing the post in case you need to encode those html entities.

Comment: I think it's here `vendor/symfony/http-foundation/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/JsonResponse.php`, function `public function setData($data = array())`, line 91